# How to import a function which is in a different directory

Tags: python, import

I am trying to calling a function from a module which is located in different directory than the current.

This is code I am using

c:\commands contains a file nlog.py which contains function parselog . i would like to                          importing  this function 
    into a python file in other directory c:\applications

```
def parselog(inFileDir = )

    ### This is in directory c:\commands which need to imported ####


c:\applications\pscan.py is the script which is calling / importing from the above file / directory

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #sys.path.append("C:/commands")
    sys.path.insert(0,'C:/commands')

from commands import nlog


def pscan (infileDir = ) 


    parselog(inFileDir=r'os.getcwd()') # I am calling the function here 






We are getting error 


NameError: global name 'parselog' is not defined


I am not sure if I am importing in a wrong way. The C:\commands folder contains _init_.py file. Please let me know what I am missing.
```

Comment: there are so many things wrong with this question, I don't know where to start...

Comment: hint 1: `from commands import nlog` tries to load the name 'nlog' (function, class, variable, whatever) from module 'commands' (and not module 'nlog' from the c:\commands directory)

Answer (score 0):

Make and empty `__init__.py` file in the folder of the module you want to import.

Answer (score -1):

Below code should work.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'c:\commands')
import nlog
parselog(inFileDir=r'os.getcwd()')
```

Comment: python translates forward slashes to backslashes transparently on windows platforms.